# Can a variable depend on an existential variable?

Tags: logic, soft-question, first-order-logic, higher-order-logic

I recently read the following article by Terence Tao: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/08/27/printer-friendly-css-and-nonfirstorderizability/#comment-472808

He writes:

“Moving on to a more complicated example, if Q(x,x’,y,y’) is a quaternary relation on four objects x,x’,y,y’, then we can express the statement

For every x and x’, there exists a y depending only on x and a y’ depending on x and x’ such that Q(x,x’,y,y’) is true

as

$\forall x \exists y \forall x' \exists y': Q(x,x',y,y')$

(note that this allows y’ to depend on y also, but this turns out to be moot, because y depends only on x)”

I don’t understand his last comment within the parantheses. Is it even possible for a variable to depend on a variable that is bound by an *existential* quantifier? I always thought that existential variables are the only type of variable that can depend on another variable and that these existential variables can only depend on universal variables. (“Existential variable” means “variable bound by an existential quantfier”, similarly “universal variable”)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables bound by existential quantifiers can depend on any previously bound variable, universal or existential ([or otherwise](http://www.math.helsinki.fi/logic/opetus/lt/beatcs.pdf)). For a silly example, consider the sentence $$\forall x\exists y\forall z\exists w(w>y+z>x).$$ Clearly the sentence is true in the natural numbers (take $y=x+1$, $w=y+z+1$), but also clearly $w$ depends on $y$.

Comment: Have you edited this answer? I thought that simewhere I've read somehting like "You are right that only variables bound by an existential quantifier can depend on something" as an answer.

Comment: @user374782 I did include that briefly, but then I removed it since I thought it was misleading. Since you caught it, though :P, let me explain why I don't like thinking that way (it's a very minor point): there are more quantifiers than just "exists" and "for all". The reason a universally bound quantifier can't "depend" on anything is that, by definition, a universally quantified expression needs to be true *no matter what* value we assign to the universally bound variable. So this is a property of the universal quantifier, specifically.

Comment: Like I said, not an important point; but that's why I ditched that phrase.

Comment: Conerning quantifiers, let me ask another question: Do you think that, for example, "There are x, y and z such that P(x,y,z)" is fundamentally the same as (i.e. just an abbreviation of) the usage of nested quantifiers "There is an x for which there is a y for which there exists a z with P(x,y,z)". Or is there also a type of " tuple-quantifier" which we use in the natural language, which can say "there is a triple x,y,z of objects with the property P(x,y,z)"? Is this an example of such another quantifier you mention?

Comment: @user374782 No, the variations you describe are all equivalent - that's just a basic existential quantifier. I'm talking about things like "There are infinitely many $x$ such that . . ." or "There are at least as many $x$ such that . . .  as there are $y$ such that . . ." or similar - quantifiers which can be given precise mathematical definitions, but cannot be expressed in first-order logic. The point is that these can still involved dependence: for instance, consider "for all $x$ there is a $y$ such that for infinitely many $z$, $x<z<y$" (which is true in the reals!). (cont'd)

Comment: On the one hand, "for infinitely many $z$" isn't just an existential quantifier; on the other hand, clearly the $z$s involved depend on $x$ and $y$. (By the way, you may also be interested in [*independence-friendly logic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence-friendly_logic), which introduces generalized quantifiers based on variable dependence!)

Comment: I think that a very large part of math can be formulated within a first-oder theory. Statements like "there are infinitely many primes" can be formalized in zfc for example, where one only has the two usual quantifiers for all and exists

Comment: @user374782 Yes, but that takes place *against the background of ZFC*. If you're talking about, say, first-order definability within a specific structure (see [model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory)) then because of this more restrictive context, generalized quantifiers provide strength beyond what first-order logic has. For an explicit example, there is no first-order sentence $\varphi$ in the language of groups which is true in exactly the finite groups (by Compactness), but we can get such a statement using "there are infinitely many" - "$\neg \exists^\infty x(x=x)$."

Comment: Similarly, by the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem, any satisfiable first-order sentence in the language of groups is true in some countable group, but "There are uncountably many $x$ such that $x=x$" is clearly true in exactly the uncountable groups. (Interestingly, these two examples "pin down" first-order logic in a certain sense: (cont'd)

Comment: [**Lindstrom's theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindstr%C3%B6m%27s_theorem) states that no logic strictly stronger than first-order logic can satisfy both Compactness and Lowenheim-Skolem. Also the proof of that theorem is a [smiley face](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Logic-Undergraduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387942580).)

Comment: Thanks for the additional information you provided! But actually I am rethinking your answer for a moment and it seems that w=y+z+1=x+1+z+1=x+z+2, so it turns out that your w really only depends on universal variables (x and z) and not on y.

Comment: @user374782 That's only true if you assume $y$ is chosen according to a known rule. Imagine the following: you have to choose $w$, and you hear what $x$ and $z$ are but not what $y$ is. Can you pick an appropriate $w$? For example, I tell you $x=5$ and $z=2$; what $w$ do you pick? Do you see why this means that $w$ really *does* depend on $y$?

Comment: Could you please check my new question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1953567/374782 and maybe answer it if you can (I am sure you can :-D)?